# Detect the network at launch & resuming to avoid crash with ReachabilitySwift

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I'm working on an iOS App in Swift1.2 and my app is crashing when there is no network.

So i would like to detect if i have network. But i would like to be able to know that at any moment, i mean when the app start or when it's resuming from the background etc. For what i saw i should write my code in the AppDelegate.swift

To perform that i'm using ReachabilitySwift but i'm not succeeding using it.

Beside avoiding the app to crash, the goal is also to print a banner displaying to the user the information that he have no network like the Facebook iOS App do. But that i'm close to it.

Thanks for you help and guidance in the Swift World

Comment: When you say "I'm not succeeding", can you provide more information? Does the project compile? Do you get errors? Do you just not get notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reachability is not guaranteed that will bring you the results at the exact moment, since it's totally asynchronous. Your app shouldn't wait for Reachability results to perform connection, there is something wrong because it shouldn't crash.

What you need to do it's add an `NSNotification` on your `AppDelegate`, to get notified when your Reachability changes.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

You can add this on your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
                                                     selector: "reachabilityChanged:", 
                                                     name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, 
                                                     object: reachability)

    reachability.startNotifier()
```

And this to show a banner, or anything you'd like to do:

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable() {
            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                println("Reachable via WiFi")
            } else {
                println("Reachable via Cellular")
            }
        } else {
            println("Not reachable")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok i get it. It's almost working but when i disable the Wifi to produce a Change i got a crash who say `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[***.AppDelegate reachabilityChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f988b609e10'`

EDIT: Ok i just found why i putted my function in private